# Create mixed list of lists with empty and filled sections?

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

With BeautifulSoup, I am trying to create a list of lists, which returns *empty lists* as well as *variables in the sequence* they appear, using this example of HTML code below...

```html
[<div class="Stats">
</div> 
<div class="Stats">
</div>
<div class="Stats">
</div>
<div class="Stats">
</div>
<div class="Stats">
</div>
<div class="Stats">
<div class="Stats__x">
<!--
-->C<!--
--></div>
</div>
<div class="Stats">
</div>
<div class="Stats">
</div>
<div class="Stats">
</div>]
```

My current code attempts are getting...

```
[['C']]
```

The result I would like to get is...

```
[[], [], [], [], [], ['C'], [], [], []]
```

I have tried many ways, creating empty list of lists by finding the number of divs  `x = len(stats = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "Stats"})`, and then with for loops attempting to append an element if it exists and leave the empty list in place if it doesn't.

```
hList = []
for each in stats:
    for each2 in each.find_all("div", {"class":"Stats__x"}):
        hList.append(each2.text.split())
```

I probably need to perform some type of index assignment but I can't figure it out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First I search all `div` with `class="Stats"` and inside every `div` I search one `div` with `class="Stats__x"`. If I get `None` then I change it into `[]`

```
data = '''<div class="Stats"></div>
<div class="Stats"></div>
<div class="Stats"></div>
<div class="Stats"></div>
<div class="Stats"></div>
<div class="Stats">
    <div class="Stats__x">
    <!--
    -->C<!--
    --></div>
</div>
<div class="Stats"></div>
<div class="Stats"></div>
<div class="Stats"></div>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

result = []

for div in soup.find_all("div", {"class": "Stats"}):
    item = div.find("div", {"class": "Stats__x"}):
    if item:
        result.append( item.text.split() )
        #result.append( [item.text.strip()] )
    else:
        result.append( [] )

print(result)
```